# How do I get the keys from a type I create in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type,

```
type CreateTodoParams = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

How can I get `title` and `description` keys from the type?

My intention would be to feed those keys to `ramda.pick`

Comment: You can't use a type as a value. Can you elaborate on your goal here?

Comment: Is there a way to check at runtime that an object I receive has only those attributes that I permit?  The object is a type of CreateTodoParams which has 2 fields `name` and `description`.  If someone passes in `title`, i want it to not to be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyof` e.g.

```
type keys = keyof CreateTodoParams
```

Comment: @user1354934 `type keys = [keyof CreateTodoParams]`

Comment: can that be used as a value?  for example, `R.pick(keys, myObject)`?  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to check at runtime that an object I receive has only those attributes that I permit?  The object is a type of CreateTodoParams which has 2 fields `name` and `description`.  If someone passes in `title`, i want it to not to be permitted.